# Google Dataflow job ( in python ) : request for Assistance in join over data sets : fixing type error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to Apache Beam on DataflowRunner.
I am trying to work on the base table and then perform CDC with delta table ( after loading the delta file in delta table.

*I am getting the below error message*

```
File "beamETL4.py", line 81, in process_id: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str [while running 'FlatMap(process_id)']
```

Any pointers will help.
Sorry I am still learning.

Details of the code :

- Code contains validation for input.
- Then reads the input file builds Pipeline.
- pipeline to load the file in delta table in BigQuery.
- Then reads the base table and the delta table calls the process function to perform
  the update.

About the data:

**Files contain 3 columns**

Column names :id, name , salary.

Data type :int, string, int

*Below is my code module*

```
"""
Author :
Vidya 


Modification History :
17-Dec-2019     Vidya       Initial Draft

"""

from __future__ import absolute_import

# Import Libraries
import argparse
import logging
import warnings
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from typing import List, Any

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


# Define custom class DataIngestion

class DataIngestion():
    """A helper class the load the file to the big query table."""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def parse_method(self, input_string):
        # Strip out carriage return, newline and quote characters.
        values = re.split(",",
                          re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', input_string)))
        row = dict(
            zip(('id', 'name', 'salary'), values)
        )
        return row


class DataLakeComparison:
    """helper class """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def base_query():
        base_query = """
        SELECT 
        id, 
        name,
        salary
        FROM CDC.base
        """
        return base_query

    def delta_query():
        delta_query = """
        SELECT 
        id, 
        name,
        salary
        FROM CDC.delta 
        """
        return delta_query

    def process_id(self, id, data):
        """This function performs the join of the two datasets."""
        result = list(data['delta'])  # type: List[Any]
        if not data['base']:
            logging.info('id is missing in base')
            return
        if not data['delta']:
            logging.info(' id is missing in delta')
            return

        base = {}
        try:
            base = data['base'][0]
        except KeyError as err:
            traceback.print_exc()
            logging.error("id Not Found error: %s", err)

        for delta in result:
            delta.update(base)

        return result


def run(argv=None):
    """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
             'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        default='gs://input-cobalt/delta1.csv'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        dest='output',
        required=False,
        help='Output BQ table to load the delta file ',
        default='CDC.delta'
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--output2',
        dest='output',
        required=False,
        help='Output BQ table to load the base table',
        default='CDC.base'
    )
    # Parse arguments from command line.
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()

    # Instantiate pipeline
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    (p
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input, skip_header_lines=1)
     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >>
     beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
                beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    known_args.output,
                    schema='id:INTEGER,name:STRING,salary:INTEGER',
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
     )
    datalakecomparison = DataLakeComparison()
    base_data = datalakecomparison.base_query()
    delta_data = datalakecomparison.delta_query()
    base_data = (
            p
            | 'Read Delta from BigQuery ' >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=base_data, use_standard_sql=True))
            |
            'Map id in base' >> beam.Map(
        lambda row: (
            row['id'], row
        )))
    delta_data = (
            p
            | 'Read Delta from BigQuery ' >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=delta_data, use_standard_sql=True))
            |
            'Map id in base' >> beam.Map(
        lambda row: (
            row['id'], row
        )))

    result = {'base': base_data, 'delta': delta_data} | beam.CoGroupByKey()
    joined = result | beam.FlatMap(datalakecomparison.process_id(result))
    joined | 'Write Data to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
        beam.io.BigQuerySink(
            known_args.output2,
            schema='id:INTEGER,name:STRING,salary:INTEGER',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))

    p.run().wait_until_finish()


# main function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Comment: Can you use different names for the queries and PCollections (i.e. not reusing `base_data` and `delta_data`)?

Comment: Hello @GuillemXercavins, it was my mistake while calling the base_query function. its fixed and now that function works but job now failed in FlatMap. when you get time, can u please check and advise. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two issues:

1. Your not allowed to mutate your inputs within a [DoFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4fc924a8193bb9495c6b7ba755ced576bb8a35d5/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L593) but the code `delta.update(base)` will mutate the input argument `data`. This could be causing an unintended side effect which later manifests in the error your getting. Please create a shallow copy of the row before updating it.
2. Did you mean to use `beam.FlatMapTuple(datalakecomparison.process_id)` instead of `beam.FlatMap(datalakecomparison.process_id(result))`. The result of the CoGroupByKey will produce records like: `(7, {'base': [{'id': 7, 'name': 'name1' , 'salary': 1}], 'delta': [{'id': 7, 'name': 'name1' , 'salary': 2}]})`. For the above example, process_id will be invoked with `id=id1` and `data={'base': [{'id': id1, 'name': 'name1' , 'salary': 1}], 'delta': ['id': id1, 'name': 'name1' , 'salary': 2]}` See [FlatMapTuple](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/flatmap/#example-5-flatmaptuple-for-key-value-pairs) for more details.